# How to save html elements to jpeg/png or pdf using python

Tags: python, html, pdf, png, jpeg

So I have an html-page:

```
<html>
    <b>Bold text</b>
    <table><tr><td>abc</td></tr></table>
</html>
```

How I can save `<b>Bold text</b>` or any html tag to jpeg/png or pdf.
Thanks.

Comment: That's a possibly surprisingly hard thing to do, the easiest way is probably to find a PDF generation library for Python that can generate from HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [HTML/CSS to PDF converter written in Python](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/) the right tool for you?

Answer (score 2):

For converting HTML to PDF in Python try [pisa](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pisa/).