# xhtml2pdf Pisa css broken none functional

Tags: python, django, pisa, xhtml2pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF using html+css using xhtml2pdf.pisa using Django. However, I'm running into all sorts of weird issues with the CSS.

Below is my code:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string
import cStringIO as StringIO
import xhtml2pdf.pisa as pisa
import cgi, os
def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    path = os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, uri.replace(settings.STATIC_URL, ""))
    return path
def test_pdf(request):
    html = render_to_string('pdf/quote_sheet.html', { 'pagesize':'A4', }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    result = StringIO.StringIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), dest=result, link_callback=fetch_resources)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('Gremlins ate your pdf! %s' % cgi.escape(html))
```

And my template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    {% load static from staticfiles %}
    {% load i18n %}
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content='{% trans "g_locale2" %}'/>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            size: A4;
            margin: 1cm;
            @frame footer {
                -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
                bottom: 0cm;
                margin-left: 9cm;
                margin-right: 9cm;
                height: 1cm;
                font-family: "Microsoft JhengHei";
            }
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Microsoft JhengHei";
            src:url('{% static "ttf/msjh.ttf" %}');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Microsoft JhengHei";
            src:url('{% static "ttf/msjhbd.ttf" %}');
        }
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Helvetica";
            src:url('{% static "ttf/Helvetica_Reg.ttf" %}');
        }
        table.styled-table tr th {
            color: gray;
            background-color: blue;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family:"Microsoft JhengHei";
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .biz_phone, .biz_fax {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            line-height: 32px;
        }
        .biz-info {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href='{% static "css/pdf.css" %}'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main-content">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="biz-info">
                <div class="biz_name">{{ proj.biz.name }}</div>
                <div class="biz_address">{{ proj.biz.address }}</div>
                <div class="biz_phone">{{ proj.biz.phone }}</div>
                <div class="biz_fax">{{ proj.biz.fax }}</div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-div">
                <table class="styled-table">
                    <tr class="row_header">
                        <th class="col_order">{% trans "g_item_num" %}</th>
                        <th class="col_name">{% trans "g_item_name" %}</th>
                        <th class="col_provider">{% trans "g_provider_name" %}</th>
                        <th class="col_budget_quantity">{% trans "g_quantity" %}</th>
                        <th class="col_price">{% trans "g_item_price" %}</th>
                        <th class="col_total_price">{% trans "g_item_total" %}</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My code is pretty basic and nothing special, they are just pretty much copied verbatim from the web. I'm running into lots of weird issues:

1. font-size, background-color works in external css, but only when applied on body or html tag.
2. width, line-height etc does not work whatsoever, no matter external, internal, or inlined.
3. margin-bottom on a parent div gets applied to every single child div instead of the parent div...
4. all sorts of other random issues...

I cannot observe a pattern from these symptoms other than just thinking the css parser and layout engine is just totally incomplete and non-functional. However I cannot find anyone online who has the same issues as me. Am I crazy? I'm not sure what is happening here... any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen this behaviour of xhtml2pdf in a different context when answering another question on here. Will try to dig into it more now I see it is not an isolated problem

Comment: Fyi this is the relevant answer - see my note re css on border-style for table element http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574976/save-the-out-table-of-a-pandas-dataframe-as-a-figure/30782222

Comment: I've read your answer in the link, i am not quite sure... are you suggesting that i use matplotlib instead for rendering table? the problem is not only with tables, but divs as well. I've made some edit in the code, the style .biz_phone, .biz_fax { display: inline-block; } works, but the width and line-height does not, and .biz-info { margin-bottom: 20px; } gets applied to all child divs biz_name, biz_address, biz_phone, biz_fax, but instead it should only apply to biz-info only... We're not just talking about CSS getting ignored, but also CSS getting applied incorrectly.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I'm just commenting that I have seen similar behaviour - it's not your mistake, not suggesting a solution yet. If I can work something out, I'll post an answer.

Comment: ok. Thank you so much. If you work out anything, please let me know!!!

Comment: I've added an answer below - not sure whether that helps at all?  It's not good news, but I think it comes down to the underlying `reportlab` module

Answer (score 11):

Under the covers, `xhtml2pdf` uses `reportlab` to actually create the PDF.

Doing some debugging - I followed the execution of parser.py in `xhtml2pdf` to see whether I could work out where the `CSS` was 'going missing' or being applied to the wrong elements.

I found that the CSS was successfully parsed and the translation into document fragments [(here in the code)](https://github.com/chrisglass/xhtml2pdf/blob/master/xhtml2pdf/parser.py#L287) worked OK, with the correct CSS elements being applied to the correct elements.

I believe the problem comes with the `reportlab` pdf rendering engine.  It is documented here.  It does not have a 1:1 mapping between CSS and the directives you can pass into it.

I first became aware of it [answering this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782222/838992). For instance in the table rendering section of the [`reportlab` documentation](http://www.reportlab.com/documentation/) (open-source User Guide, chapter 7, page 76), it is obvious that there is no analogue for the `border-style` CSS attribute - so although in theory you can specify a border style and no error will be thrown, that value will be ignored.

While investigating CSS to pdf mapping, I found [this software (Javascript)](https://github.com/Xportability/css-to-pdf) that also maps HTML/CSS to pdf.  I tried that on the HTML from this question and the other one I linked to.  This manages to render the pages correctly into the pdf document, so I believe this is not a fundamental limitation of the pdf document specification, but rather of the `reportlab` module.

It seems to me this is a problem for `xhtml2pdf`.  It seems particularly bad for tables, but obviously affects other types of document too.  Sorry not to resolve your problem, but I hope this goes some way towards explaining it.